# $f$ and $g$ continuously diff. homeomorphisms from R^k to a shared subset of R^n (k<n) with full rank Jacobians. Is $f^{-1}\circ g$ a diffeomorphism?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Let $A, B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^k$ be open sets and $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, with $k < n$. Let $f:A \rightarrow C$ and $g:B \rightarrow C$ be two continuously differentiable homeomorphisms with full rank Jacobian matrices everywhere on their respective supports.

Can we guarantee that the map $g^{-1} \circ f$ is a diffeomorphism from $A$ to $B$? If not, what additional conditions on $f$ and $g$ would do the trick? Any reference would be appreciated.

Comment: if $C$ is a submanifold: yes, because then $f$ and $g$ are diffeomorphisms by inverse function theorem.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to avoid making explicit assumptions about $C$? For instance, could we show that $C$ actually has to be a submanifold from the properties of $f$ alone?

Comment: @psl2Z, could you expand a little about how to use the inverse function theorem to show that $f$ and $g$ are diffeomorphisms? The inverse function theorem I know applies to functions from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 1):

If we have smooth manifolds $M,N$ and a $C^1$ map $F: M \to N$ such that $DF_p$ is a linear isomorphism for some $p \in M$, then there are neighborhoods $U$ of $p$ and $V$ of $F(p)$ such that $F: U \to V$ is a $C^1$-diffeomorphism.

$C$ gets an embedded submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by $f$ or $g$, because $f,g$ are injective immersions and topological embeddings. The manifold structure of $C$ does therefore not depend on $f$ or $g$. $f,g$ are then $C^1$-diffeomorphisms and therefore $g^{-1}\circ f$ too.